update fasterxml jackson from 2.17 to 2.18 lead error "no delegate- or property-based Creator" in kotlin
After update jackson kotlin module from 2.17 to 2.18 I have strange errors.
DTO is
data class StopWordModifyRequest(
    @field:NotEmpty
    @field:Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    val word: String,
) : Serializable

test
        mvc
            .post(API_ROUTE) {
                addCommonHeaders(KNOWN_USER_ID, ADMIN_ROLE)
                content = """
                    {
                        "word": "childTest"
                    }
                """
            }.andExpect { status { isCreated() } }

it works in 2.17, but error in 2.18:
Body = {"message":"Request body is invalid","details":[{"name":null,"description":"Cannot construct instance of `x.y.z.StopWordModifyRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 3, column: 25]"}]}

I can't google it quickly

hmm https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/846
